# SQL Server trigger in database a should input row in database b with different user

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

We have a system that stores tens of thousands of databases, each holding the data of a customer subscribing to our services. Each of those databases has their own user that is known and used by the custom thorough the distributed, thick, application front-ends we provide.

Now I would like to add a trigger to one of the tables in each one of those dbs, that should update one common db with some of the data from the inserted rows. Sort of a many-to-one db scenario if you will...

This new common db can be set up pretty much how we like - as far as users/permissions and so on, and the trigger we insert in the old dbs can be written pretty freely. But we can not change those customer dbs as far as users/permissions.

Currently I'm experimenting with using the guest user, it has been given writing access, on the common db (named "foo" in example below) like this, but it is not working (i think due to the guest user of the common db not being allowed to access the customer db table - named Bf in example below - it is triggered in?). It may also be that I'm using "execute as" where I should be using execute as login="? I'm having a hard time finding a comprehensible place that describes the difference.

This is the trigger we would like to get working, and inserted in every customer db:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[Bf]
WITH EXECUTE AS 'guest'
FOR INSERT
AS 
begin 
    insert into [foo].[dbo].[baar]
           (publicKey, fileId) 
    SELECT b.publicKey, a.autoId 
    FROM client_db_1.[dbo].[Integrationer] as b, inserted as a where 
a.autoId in (select top 1 autoId from inserted order by autoId)

end
```

As you may guess, I'm not an experienced user of triggers or sql permissions/access work. But the info we want to collect is harmless, and it should take close to 0 time to execute, and in a secured, non-exposed, environment, so I'm very willing to read/learn if anyone has advice?

/Henry

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using a message queue for this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be instantaneous like that? I much more resilient/reliable to pull the data out of the source database on various intervals. Triggers are usually considered a last resort

Comment: Interesting @p.marino! Question: would that still use triggers to fire the message-sending to Service Broker? Or is it different tech altogether? And also, does it require any permissions or prerequisites on the sending db or user in my case above?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid! We thought about that but would rather not have a polling-based solution but rather have a chain of events happen when the customer actually inserts a row in that particular table (and pretty real time when that happens).

Comment: @HenryArousell - I am far from an expert on SQL-Server but this would be what I would investigate if I were you. The trigger will create the message and put it in a queue where the "common DB" will consume it (and update its own tables). This would solve all the user/privileges problems.
If you want to avoid triggers altogether you could make the "message sending" a part of the normal update logic (but of course this would require more work for you). Try looking for more Message Queue q&a here on StackOverflow, maybe.

Comment: I will @p.marino, and report back here what I find! Thank you!